# Rails routing and http requests to application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want my delivery controller to receive URL parameters similar to this:

```
https://www.xxxxx.com/messages/delivery?id=ones1sbn&type=1
```

My `.delivery` action in `MessagesController` looks like this:

```
def delivery
  sent_message =  SentMessage.find_by_ref(params[:id])
  if params[:type] == 1
    sent_message.delivery = "Delivered"
    sent_message.save()
  elsif params[:type] == 2
    sent_message.delivery = "Delivery Failure"
    sent_message.save()
  else 
    sent_message.save() 
  end
end
```

Then the routing entry is

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    get 'delivery'
  end
end
```

What could be the reason I'm not able to receive the information from the incoming HTTP request?

the filters in the messages controller are

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:delivery, :show]
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:delivery, :show]
```

rake routes for this action

```
 delivery_messages GET        /messages/delivery(.:format)                          messages#delivery
```

After all the update the error is now;

```
Template is missing

Missing template messages/delivery, application/delivery with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim, :arb]}. Searched in: * "/var/www/html/webapp/app/views" * "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views" * "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/app/views"
```

Template was added but still no updates from the http request

Answer (score 1):

Use `get` instead of `match`, like so:

```
get 'messages/delivery' => 'messages#delivery'
```

**Update**

Based on your comment, it sounds like you have a restful resource path in your routes.rb file that is matching the URL first before it reaches the `get` delivery line. Probably something like `resources :messages`.

As I said in the comment remember that route matches are examined in the order they appear in that file. You can either place the `get` above the `resouces` line, or try this:

```
resources :messages do
    collection do
        get :delivery
    end
end
```

That should map `messages/delivery` to the `:delivery` action in your `MessagesController`. Do a `rake routes` to verify.

Comment: For a request like this 'https://www.xxxxxx.com/messages/delivery?id=og95uijj&type=1'I get this error; 'Couldn't find Message with id=delivery'

Comment: @acacia Remember that routes in your routes.rb file are examined in the order they appear, so most likely you have something that is catching the request before it gets down to your delivery line. You probably have `resources :messages` first, I'm guessing. If you post your routes.rb file I can give you a more direct answer; or see the update I'm about to make in a second and see if that helps.

Comment: @acacia Yeah you can use a string or a symbol, makes no difference. I assume that worked then?

Comment: The action in the controller is not responding to the http request. could there be something wrong with the controller to be precise the delivery action?

Comment: @acacia Given the code you've posted there should be no reason for it to fail. If you have any before filters in either the `MessagesController` or `ApplicationController`, and they cause a render or redirect action (such as failed login credentials for example), your controller action will never execute. Examine the log output when the URL is requested and see what its doing; you should see `Processed by MessagesController#delivery as ...` if it is successfully entering your action method. Set a logger message at the top of the controller action too to further verify, and debug from there.

Comment: @acacia Additionally, do a `rake routes` to double check the path and controller#action arrangement.

Comment: @acacia I have no idea, there could be many reasons for this error. This is too localized at this point, you're gonna have to debug the project and figure it out. Do you actually need something to be rendered/returned from this action? if not you can always do `render :nothing=>true`.